[tag][LyX] Inserting hyperlink gives "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref."
The message
The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [pdftex]
Adding the global options:
  ,pdftex
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.

As advised, added "pdftex" to [Document-> Settings -> Document Class -> Class Options] does not help.
Done [Export->"LaTeX plain)] and found the problem:
%% LyX 2.4.0 created this file.  For more info, see https://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[british,american,doc, 11pt, a4paper]{apa7}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{note_fontcolor}{rgb}{0.800781, 0.800781, 0.800781}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[]
 {hyperref}

There is "\usepackage{Hyperref}" that is not resulting from "[Document->Settings->PDF Properties->Use hyperref Support].  If the option is selected:
%% LyX 2.4.0 created this file.  For more info, see https://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[british,american,doc, 11pt, a4paper]{apa7}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{note_fontcolor}{rgb}{0.800781, 0.800781, 0.800781}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}


Still the the same error message
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref

The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [pdftex,pdfusetitle, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=fal
se, breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]

Adding the global options:
  ,pdftex,pdfusetitle, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=fal
se, breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.

So, IMHO, the problem:

Package hyperref is \usepackage by the core code of LyX, not the DocumentClass (apa7 - I checked)
The require option "pdftex" is an option of hyperref that must be specified as part of \usepackage (See CTAN manual).
Therefore, setting in [Document->Settings->PDF Properties->Additional Options] that resulting in \hypersetup will not work.
The LyX core code do not interpret pdftex in "[Document-> Settings -> Document Class -> Class Options]", or the code generating "\usepackage{hyperref}" did not interpret Class Options to deter presence od "pdftex".

Please advice if there are other means to avoid this pesky error message.
Thanks!

Using the pdftex is in the best case useless and in the worst case the source or errors. Don't use it.

The apa7 class automatically loads hyperref. You shouldn't load it a second time with different options.

The "pdftex" is automagically requested by LyX (See the error message).  That was the beginning of the problem.   In the apa7 GitHub (https://github.com/BenMobility/Overleaf/tree/main), I see only this line "\RequirePackage{scalerel,tikz,hyperref} % this is included for ORCID icon" - is this what you meant "automatically load hyperref" ?

Yes, that's where the class automatically loads hyperref.

Thanks!  If I do not insert hyperlinks anywhere in the document, the error message do not appear. This told me that hyperref somehow triggered the need for pdftex. How to avoid needing pdftex when using hyperref in LyX 2.4.0?  What did I do wrong? or did not do?

The pdftex option is not needed for hyperref.

I did a very small file, using Article (Standard Class), included a statement with a hyperlink.  No error was produced.  Then I added  \usepackage{hyperref} in preamble - it produced no error. In both cases, the PDF produced do not have clickable links.  Finally, I changed to apa6, and then apa7 - both produced the error, but both has clickable link in PDF.  Therefore, I concur to your advices that hyperref do not trigger the need for pdftex, but apa7.cls.  I stand corrected saying apa7 is not the cause - it did pulled in hyperref, and somehow, something needed pdftex. Thanks again.

To close off the issue, git clone https://github.com/dan-weiss/apa7-latex-cls-source (see https://ctan.org/pkg/apa7 documentation), generated apa7.cls, edit the generated source to separately load hyperref with pdftex option, before the original "\RequirePackage{scalerel,tikz,hyperref}" (becoming \RequirePackage{scalerel,tikz}". Created a LyX custom layout file at my local directory, and use the class [Document->Settings->Document Class->Local Class].    With this, the error message reported above was removed.

Also noticed the following line in the "Complete Log":
"This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.6.25)  25 JUN 2024 17:44
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled."
Somehow, LyX 2.4.0 is using pdfftex.

apa7.cls is licensed under the LaTeX Project Public License. It very strongly discourages to edit file without changing their name

Rest assured, understood.  The change was made to investigate (I named it 'apa7x26' during the test so not to confuse myself). Doing further tests, and will communicate with the owner about this topic in due course. Thanks for your guidance.
